# User Dashboard and Edit Profile for Organization

Tags: permissions, user-dashboard, organization

We have set up a User dashboard for individuals, and a profile so individuals can update their address, phone, email, etc. It looks like this:
[image]

We would like to set up something similar for an Organization, so permissioned users can see the organization's membership expiration date, and update the contact info for the organization.

I understand that the way to do this is to set a permissioned relationship, so the individual can view and edit the Organization. However, if I click the Organization, it doesn't take me to a user dashboard for the Organization, but a contact view as if an administrator were logged in. Membership information is not visible. The edit function is not a profile with limited fields, but all the fields an administrator could edit (see below photos):
[image]
[image]
[image]

Am I missing something? Is there a way to see a user dashboard for an organization, like there is for an individual? Can I limit the organizational fields that can be edited?

I am using CiviCRM 5.31.0 with WordPress.

Access control:  Subscriber (the user) can:  view my contact, edit my contact, access contact dashboard

Relationship permission:  set to view and update

EDIT pd added image showing what dmaster shows for comparison

[image]

Comment: if A works for B, and A is permissioned to Edit B, and A has access to their own Contact Dashboard, then they should be able to access a profile to edit B. Not sure if that is what you are after but it didn't seem to be covered in your description

Comment: We'd like A to be able to access the user dashboard for B, and a profile to edit B's information. Neither is currently the case; clicking the link for B leads to the second and third photos in my post above. Is there a different way to access a profile to edit B?

Comment: on dmaster, as user/1 if i go to my dashboard https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/user?reset=1 i see an Org, and if i click the Edit Contact Info and right click to open in new tab it takes me to eg https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/relatedcontact?action=update&reset=1&cid=185&rcid=203
is that same as with your set up?

Comment: or this in the case of their Employer which I just added. https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/relatedcontact?action=update&reset=1&cid=47&rcid=203

Comment: Sorry, I can't access the links you provided and the site won't let me create an account.

Comment: all the demo sites just have login / pw as demo | demo

Comment: but they get refreshed every 24 hours so not sure if it will still be there. but easy enough for you to follow what i did and repeat isn't it?

Comment: Got it, thank you! I see what you're talking about. On the demo site, the links I'm seeing by the Org are "Edit Contact Information" and "Dashboard," which looks like what we want. But that's not what I'm seeing on my site. The links there are "View" and "Edit."

Comment: I added another picture to my original post. The second picture now shows how the Organization shows up in the user dashboard, and the links it gives.

Comment: I added a shot from dmaster for comparison. odd. not sure how you would have config on your system that is changing this. worth disabling extensions just to check there isn't something else affecting this.

Answer (score 2):

We have used [contact layout](https://civicrm.org/extensions/contact-layout-editor) editor extension to show only necessary fields on view contact section. Using contact layout editor you can customize the view contact page. You can include profiles with limited fields and hide or remove the edit option via css or JS.

Or other option is write extension to redirect Org contact to /civicrm/contact/dashboard?cid=123&reset=1

AFAIK having Relationship permission: set to view and update will only allow user to updated the related contact details but not Payments or Membership. Try giving 'Access civi membership' permission to user role

Answer (score 2):

If you want a user to only edit specific fields for their organisation you can create a profile and add the organisation fields you want to give them access to. From the CiviCRM profiles page:

> CiviCRM Profile(s) allow you to aggregate groups of fields and include
> them in your site as input forms, contact display pages, and search
> and listings features. They provide a powerful set of tools for you to
> collect information from constituents and selectively share contact
> information.

Profiles can be used to list contacts, create new contacts or edit contacts. For your requirement, the profile would be a standalone form profile for editing. When you create a link to the profile edit form, you'll need to make sure you pass the organisaton contact ID in the URL as one of the parameters. For instance, if your profile form had an ID of 6, and the organisation contact ID was 18 then your URL would be:

`www.mydomain.com/civicrm/profile/edit?gid=6&id=18&reset=1`

Note that the query parameter label for the contact ID is `id`, not `cid`. The `gid` query parameter refers to the id of the profile form.

To ensure the correct permissions to allow access to the profile, you may need to update the civicrm ACL permissions at `/civicrm/acl?reset=1`.

**Note**: if you do not pass the organisation ID parameter correctly in the URL then you'll get a warning message saying:

> This profile is configured for contact type 'Organization'. It cannot
> be used to edit contacts of other types.

Comment: So if I have created this profile for the org record, and I have a related individual record which is permission to view and edit the org, can I send a checksum link to the individual in email that will take them to the pre-filled org profile, and update it without them having to log in?

Comment: Something like www.mydomain.com/civicrm/profile/edit?gid=6&id=18&reset=1&cid=indivcontactid&checksum

Comment: I haven't used a checksum link before so not sure if this will work. You might want to ask a seperate question about this.